# Installing PHP on IIS server: standard FastGCI installation or Zend Server CE

Tags: windows-server-2008, php, iis, zend-server-ce

I am installing my first production server with Windows. It is virtual server running on KVM with 1 GB RAM and 30 GB disc space. As operating system will be used Windows Web Server 2008 (not R2 version). Mainly it will host open-source CMS written in PHP - Drupal, maybe WordPress. Secondly it will host my own applications written in ASP.NET (but it will be nothing of size of Drupal).

To my question: Should I install PHP on IIS by standard Microsoft recommended methods by FastGCI module, PHP installation from php.net and maybe PHP Manager for IIS 7 module, or should I install Zend Server CE which should do pretty much everything (I do not intend install Apache webserver but use it in conjunction with IIS) itself?

Whole server will be for new webs so there is no immediately need to setup minimal performance level.

Thanks for answers.

Edit: My question is more about the composition of Zend Server and its cache and optimizer when compared with a standard installation on IIS, when hosting an open source CMS, not so much about configuring PHP.

Answer (score 0):

For sheer laziness/ease of use, try the [Web Platform Installer](http://www.microsoft.com/web/downloads/platform.aspx). You can even pick which CMS you want to use with it, and it'll be configured for you.

Comment: Well, it is not because of laziness or easy of use. Set up PHP is actually pretty simple on Windows, but my question target more on composition of Zend Server and it's cache and optimizer in confrontation with standard installation when hosting open/source CMS.